# Running a macro crashes excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel spreadsheet containing around 15 excel DCT. 
On that sheet, there is a drop down menu allowing selecting a username, and when changing the value, a macro updates all the DTC present on the spreadsheet with the username and refreshes the data.
Problem is that now for any reason, it crashes excel except on high perf computer.
I don't know what to do

Here is the macro :

```
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim pi As PIVOTITEM
Dim strField As String

strField = "Cslts"

On Error Resume Next
'Application.EnableEvents = False
'Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    If Target.Address = Range("H1").Address Then


            For Each pt In ActiveSheet.PivotTables
                With pt.PageFields(strField)
                    For Each pi In .PivotItems
                        If pi.Value = Target.Value Then
                            .CurrentPage = Target.Value
                    Exit For

                        Else
                            .CurrentPage = "(blank)"

                        End If
                    Next pi
                End With
            Next pt

    End If

End Sub
```

Regards,

Comment: When debugging, you should always avoid `On Error Resume Next` as it will mask the errors you are looking for. Likewise, it should only be in your code if you are looking for a specific error that the code then deals with.

Comment: you can make the If block more efficient by setting a boolean value to true if `pi.Value = Target.Value`, then only set `.CurrentPage = "(blank)"` if that boolean value is not set. Right now you set the .currentpage` value on *every* loop if and until the `pi = target`. My change will help with performance (possibly in a big way).

Comment: Hi Scott, thanks for the suggestion but could you clarify as I am not sure to understand exactly how to change that ?

Comment: To echo what @DougGlancy said -- using `On Error Resume Next` like that is a major red flag. In effect you are using it as `On Error Hide Bug`. Hidden bugs are hard to fix. If you find that your code won't run without that line -- fix the code rather than suppress the errors. Suppressed errors often lead to nonsensical results or eventually blow up on you (by, say, crashing Excel).

Comment: See my answer provided below @dlan

Comment: There is no need to loop through each of the pivot items, just set the `pi` object to the required value and validate it afterwards.  It also seems that you are not disabling the Application Events (by the lack of `Application.EnableEvents = True` at the end) if so the worksheet event is triggered again every time the PivotField page is changed and that could be the cause of Excel crashing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to loop through each of the `PivotItems`, just set the `pi` object to the required value and validate it afterwards.

It also it seems that you are not disabling the `Application.Events` (by the lack of `Application.EnableEvents = True` at the end of the procedure), if so the worksheet event is triggered again every time the `PivotField` page is changed and that could be the cause of Excel crashing.

Be aware that if the `PivotField(strField)` is not set as a `PageField` you’ll get a `"Run-time error 1004: Unable to get the PageFields property of the PivotTable class"` therefore the `PivotField(strField)` need to be validated as a `PageField` *(see below in the code)*.

Assuming that the procedure is a `Worksheet Change Event` try this *(see comments in the code)*:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim pf As PivotField
Dim pi As PivotItem
Dim strField As String

    strField = "Cslts"

    Application.EnableEvents = False    'This avoids the Worksheet event from restarting again every time the PivotTable page is changed.
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    If Target.Address = "$H$1" Then
        For Each pt In Target.Worksheet.PivotTables

            Rem Set PageField
            Set pf = Nothing
            On Error Resume Next
            Set pf = pt.PageFields(strField)
            On Error GoTo 0

            Rem Validate PageField
            If Not (pf Is Nothing) Then
                With pf
                    .EnableMultiplePageItems = False

                    Rem Set PageField Item
                    Set pi = Nothing                    'Initialize Item object
                    On Error Resume Next                'This will avoid an error if the item is not present
                    Set pi = .PivotItems(Target.Value2) 'No need to loop through the items just set the required item
                    On Error GoTo 0                     'Clears the Error Object

                    Rem Validate & Set PageField Item
                    If Not (pi Is Nothing) Then
                        .CurrentPage = Target.Value2
                    Else
                        .CurrentPage = "(blank)"

    End If: End With: End If: Next: End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    End Sub
```

Additionally, suggest to refresh the `PivotTables` to ensure you are working with the latest update from the source data, also be aware of the different values the `PivotItem` properties `Value` and `SourceName` could have.

Suggest to read the following pages to gain a deeper understanding of the resources used:

[On Error Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251688.aspx),

[PivotCache Object (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838795.aspx), [PivotFields Object (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff192974.aspx), [PivotItems Object (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840045.aspx)

Comment: nice one. this is more efficient than my answer and where I wanted to go if my brain would have taken me that far :)

Comment: Hi, from what I see, this seem to work but I get an error 1004 impossible to read PageFields property in PivotTable class the debug highlights this line : With pt.PageFields(strField)

Comment: Hi ok got rid of the 1004 error but I get error 91 on line .CurrentPage = "(blank)"

Comment: Sorry could not reproduce 'Run-time error 91: Object variable or With block variable not set'. Did you copy the code as provided?

Comment: Hi, yes everything works nearly fine except that I still get err 1004 as explained above but on line With pt.PageFields(strField), I thought I got rid of it but infact .. no :-(

Comment: You get `Run-time error 1004: Unable to get the PageFields property of the PivotTable class’ when the PivotField `strField` is not set as a `PageField` (see edited answer).

Answer (score 1):

I agree that `On Error Resume Next` should be removed as it will mask any potential errors causing the code to crash.

I also know from experience that updating multiple PivotTables can be very taxing on performance, especially if the data source is very large.

That said, one way you can improve the performance of this code is by adjusting the `IF` block to only only change the `.CurrentPage` value of the Page Field **once** for each PivoTable. The way you have it now will change the value *for each test on the pivot item* - which, depending on the amount of items in the field, could be asking Excel to do a lot. In other words, you asking Excel to manually set the CurrentPage value to blank *each time the pivot item does not equal the username*.

**Refactored Code Below**

```
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim pi As PivotItem
Dim strField As String

strField = "Cslts"

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

If Target.Address = Range("H1").Address Then

    For Each pt In ActiveSheet.PivotTables

        With pt.PageFields(strField)

            For Each pi In .PivotItems

                If pi.Value = Target.Value Then

                    Dim bUserNameFound
                    bUserNameFound = True

                    Exit For

                End If

            Next pi

            If bUserNameFound Then
                .CurrentPage = Target.Value
            Else
                .CurrentPage = "(blank)"
            End If

        End With

    Next pt

End If
```